# Not able to mock connection.prepareCall method

Tags: spring, spring-boot, mockito, powermock, spring-boot-test

I am not able to mock connection.prepareCall("{call myStoreProcedure()}"); call in spring boot project.

Every time i am getting "***org.h2.jdbc.JdbcSQLSyntaxErrorException: Column "myStoreProcedure" not found***; SQL statement:", because i am using h2 database and there we dont have that procedure. But when i mock it should not call the database it should return the mock value only..but its not happening.

***Note : I am getting above exception but my test cases are passing.***

Below is the my code snippet :

```
package com.khan;

import static org.mockito.Mockito.mock;

import java.sql.CallableStatement;
import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.ResultSet;

import javax.sql.DataSource;

import org.junit.Test;
import org.junit.runner.RunWith;
import org.mockito.Mock;
import org.mockito.Mockito;
import org.powermock.api.mockito.PowerMockito;
import org.powermock.core.classloader.annotations.PowerMockIgnore;
import org.powermock.core.classloader.annotations.PrepareForTest;
import org.powermock.modules.junit4.PowerMockRunner;
import org.powermock.modules.junit4.PowerMockRunnerDelegate;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.boot.test.context.SpringBootTest;
import org.springframework.test.context.TestPropertySource;
import org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner;

@RunWith(PowerMockRunner.class)
@PowerMockRunnerDelegate(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@PrepareForTest({ DataSource.class, Connection.class, CallableStatement.class })
@SpringBootTest
@PowerMockIgnore({ "javax.management.*", "javax.net.ssl.*", "javax.security.auth.*" })
@TestPropertySource({ "classpath:application.properties" })
public class MainClassTest {

    @Autowired
    MainClass mainClass;

    @Autowired
    private DataSource dataSource;
    
    @Test
    public void testMethod() throws Exception {
        ResultSet resultSet = mock(ResultSet.class);
        CallableStatement callableStatement = mock(CallableStatement.class);
        Mockito.when(dataSource.getConnection()).thenReturn(connection);
        Mockito.when(connection.prepareCall("{  call myprocedure()}")).thenReturn(callableStatement);
        Mockito.when(callableStatement.executeQuery()).thenReturn(resultSet);
        
        //Tried below one as well but no luck
        //PowerMockito.stub(PowerMockito.method(Connection.class, "prepareCall", Mockito.any())).toReturn(callableStatement);
        
        mainClass.callProcedure("Procedure Name");
    }

}
```

Below is my MainClass :

```
 public class MainClass{
    @Autowired
    private DataSource dataSource;
        
    public void callProcedure(String storedProcName) throws SQLException {
            Connection connection = dataSource.getConnection();
            try (CallableStatement cs = connection.prepareCall("{call " + storedProcName + "}");) { // I am getting exception here but test cases are passing
                cs.executeQuery();
            } catch (SQLException e) {
                log.error("Exception occured while execution of stored procedure having storedProcName: {} with reason: {} "
                        + e.getMessage(), storedProcName, e);
                throw e;
            }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I see lot of issues in your testCase.

1. No need to load Spring Context for testing this class. Mock should be enough.
2. In your callProcedure you are passing **"Procedure Name"** but in mock you expect **"{  call myprocedure()}"** so that mock will never get triggered.
3. Your test case passes as you not verifying anything.

Try something like below.

```
@RunWith(PowerMockRunner.class)
public class MainClassTest {

    @InjectMocks
    MainClass mainClass;

    @Mock
    private DataSource dataSource;
    
    @Test
    public void testMethod() throws Exception {
        //Given
        ResultSet resultSet = mock(ResultSet.class);
        CallableStatement callableStatement = mock(CallableStatement.class);
        Mockito.when(dataSource.getConnection()).thenReturn(connection);
        Mockito.when(connection.prepareCall(anyString())).thenReturn(callableStatement);
        Mockito.when(callableStatement.executeQuery()).thenReturn(resultSet);
        
        //When
        mainClass.callProcedure("Procedure Name");

        //Then
        verify(dataSource, times(1)).getConnection();
    }
}
```